# get shops inside a polygon using google api

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get shops inside the drawn polygon but not able to find any solution.  I have multiple polygons in map and needs to shows count of particular type of shop for each polygon.

```
geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': placeName
                }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var geometry = results[0].geometry,
                            places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(bgMap);
                        places.nearbySearch({
                            bounds: bounds,
                            types: [
                                'establishment'
                            ]
                        }, function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: results[i].geometry.location,
                                        map: bgMap
                                    }));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        //console.log(markers);
                    } else {
                        return $('#map').html('could not locate you');
                    }
                });
```

bounds is list of coordinates;

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. This will bring more attention to your question (otherwise it sounds like "write this code for me", which is not encouraged here).

Comment: i don't want to add address also in geocode as i am searching for shops inside a block group.

Comment: So bascially `nearbySearch` is the function you try to use to find those shops, right?

Comment: Yes, we have one more application where we are using nearbysearch to find shops with keywords for a radii. Here also i will be using keywords actually and not types.